# How to configure a custom findbugs task in gradle with a different pluginClasspath

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I tried to set up a custom findbugs task with gradle which will have a different pluginClasspath than the default ones.

So the default tasks should use the default FindBugs rules while the custom one should use the findbugs-security rules. My configuration looks like this:

```
dependencies {
  findbugsPlugins 'com.h3xstream.findsecbugs:findsecbugs-plugin:1.4.4'
}

findbugs {
  // general config
}

task findbugsSecurity(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: classes) {
  classes = fileTree(project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
  source = project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  classpath = files()

  pluginClasspath = files(configurations.findbugsPlugins.asPath)
}
```

However, if I run the findbugsMain task now, it also includes the checks from findbugs-security!

How can I configure it so that findbugs-security checks are only used in the custom task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like configuring the `findbugsSecurity` task is also changing the behavior of `findbugsMain` as you've probably guessed.

The trick is to use a new configuration because Gradle will automatically look for dependencies for the findbugsPlugins configuration and that will apply to all invocations of findbugs (See [pluginClasspath part of FindBugs DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs:pluginClasspath)):

```
configurations {
   foo
}

dependencies {
  // Important that we use a new configuration here because Gradle will use the findbugsPlugins configurations by default
  foo 'com.h3xstream.findsecbugs:findsecbugs-plugin:1.4.4'
}

findbugs { /* whatever */ }

task findbugsSecurity(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: classes) {
  classes = fileTree(project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
  source = project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  classpath = files()
  pluginClasspath = files(configurations.foo.asPath)
}
```

Comment: Great! I didn't see in the documentation that 'findbugsPlugins' dependencies are used by default for the findbugs plugin